# Sorting Terraform variables.tf by variable name using Python

Tags: python, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on creating a new VPC where I need to provide some variables as input.

All the variables are listed in `variables.tf`. The file is very long (I only copied couple of them here) and variables are defined in no particular order.

I need to find a **Pythonic way** to sort my `variables.tf` by **variable name**.

```
variable "region" {
  description = "The region to use when creating resources"
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-1"
}

variable "create_vpc" {
  description = "Controls if VPC should be created"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "name" {
  description = "Name to be used, no default, required"
  type        = string
}
```

The **sorted** `variables.tf` should look like this:

```
variable "create_vpc" {
  description = "Controls if VPC should be created"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "name" {
  description = "Name to be used, no default, required"
  type        = string
}

variable "region" {
  description = "The region to use when creating resources"
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-1"
}
```

Comment: There is [python-hcl2](https://pypi.org/project/python-hcl2/) which would enable you to parse your TF code. Once you have this, it should be able to manipulate it, including sorting.

Answer (score 0):

"Pythonic" might be the wrong approach here - you are still comfortably sitting behind a python interpreter, but for better or worse (worse) you are playing by Terraform's rules. Check out the links below. Hashicorp "enables" python via their CDK, and there are several other projects out there on github.

Once you are up and running with something like that, and you have Terraform fully ported over to your Python setup, *then* you can start thinking pythonic. </IMO>

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk
https://github.com/beelit94/python-terraform/blob/develop/python_terraform/terraform.py

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came across last year https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12959 and is why I created https://gist.github.com/yermulnik/7e0cf991962680d406692e1db1b551e6 out of curiosity. Not Python but `awk` :shrugging:
Simple `awk` script to sort TF files. Not just variables, but any of 1st level resource definition blocks.